# php - generate time limited download link for files on another server

Tags: php, download

I put my files on my VPS and user can direct download all files. but I want to hide my actual file paths and make time limited download links. I googled it and find some solutions but most of them was for files that were on same server and some of them has some coding in VPS side, but i can't write any php code on my VPS because it doesn't support php. 
also I try some script that works well but generated link wasn't resumable and didn't show file size until download finished. How can I solve these problems?

Comment: if you have a VPS You should have root access to it? If so, make it support PHP by installing `php5`? and if this is done through PHP you will require the use of a database, to contain all the path, filename, download count and time remaining.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mod_auth_token (http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/) apache module, if you are running apache as web frontend.
This is how you can handle the PHP side of the token generation process:

```
<?php
// Settings to generate the URI
$secret = "secret string";             // Same as AuthTokenSecret
$protectedPath = "/downloads/";        // Same as AuthTokenPrefix
$ipLimitation = false;                 // Same as AuthTokenLimitByIp
$hexTime = dechex(time());             // Time in Hexadecimal
//$hexTime = dechex(time()+120);         // Link available after 2 minutes      
$fileName = "/file_to_protect.txt";    // The file to access


// Let's generate the token depending if we set AuthTokenLimitByIp
if ($ipLimitation) {
  $token = md5($secret . $fileName . $hexTime . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
}
else {
  $token = md5($secret . $fileName. $hexTime);
}

// We build the url
$url = $protectedPath . $token. "/" . $hexTime . $fileName;
echo $url;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant make changes to the actual downloadlinks they will stay available for download until they are deleted from the server.
Of course you can make a Script which encrypts the download URL based on the system time, but once the user calls them within time he gets the decrypted URL from the script.